# При наведении на картинку-иконку появлялся затемненный круг с текстом

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Доброго времени суток, дорогие гуру. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой и не смог найти на неё решение. Нужно сделать так, что бы при наведении на картинку-иконку появлялся затемненный круг с текстом.

Прошу хотя бы подтолкнуть к правильному решению, уже и вправду не знаю что делать:

```
<div class="col-md-12 pre">
  <div class="sss"><p>Наши преимущества:</p></div>
  <div class="col-md-4"><div class="comf"><img src="images/ico/kreslo.png"><p>Комфортные условия</p></div></div>

  <div class="col-md-4"><div class="health"><img src="images/ico/serdce.png"><p>Здоровье</p></div></div>

  <div class="col-md-4"><div class="razv"><img src="images/ico/kerpeach.png"><p>Развитие</p></div></div>

  <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 6%;"><div class="comf"><img src="images/ico/kasha.png"><p>Питание</p></div></div>

  <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 6%;"><div class="health"><img src="images/ico/cena.png"><p>Честная цена</p></div></div>

  <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 6%;"><div class="razv"><img src="images/ico/mingr.png"><p>Мини-группы</p></div></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Приложите картинку с желаемым результатом.

Answer (score 3):

Предположу:

```css
p {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

p:hover,
img:hover+p {
  opacity: 1;
}

.col-md-4>div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  
<div class="col-md-12 pre">
  <div class="sss"><p>Наши преимущества:</p></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="comf">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
      <p>Комфортные условия</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="health">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200">
      <p>Здоровье</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="razv">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
      <p>Развитие</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 6%;">
    <div class="comf">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200">
      <p>Питание</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 6%;">
    <div class="health">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200">
      <p>Честная цена</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top: 6%;">
    <div class="razv">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200">
      <p>Мини-группы</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Работает как часы.